# Django Selenium click button on ajax modal pop-up window

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I'm currently doing some task for my university. I'm writing Django Selenium tests for my app. I'm trying to write test for deleting object.

They key parts of my code are:

delete confirmation.html

```
<form action="" method="post" id="confirmForm">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>{% trans "Are you sure you want to delete this car?" %}</p>
    <input class="center-block btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Confirm' %}"/>
</form>
```

modal.js

```
function showModal(url) {
    $("#myModalBody").text();
    $("#myModal").modal();
    $.ajax({
        url,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        $("#myModalBody").html(html);
        $("#confirmForm").attr('action', url);
    });

}
```

When I click following button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left" value="" id="car-delete-modal-btn m-10-b" onclick="showModal('{% url 'c2crental:delete_car' details_car.id %}');">{% trans "Delete car" %}</button>
```

[Modal appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GepXP.png)

And test stops with result: Unable to locate element. I was trying to use different selectors but none of them worked. For now test looks like this:

```
# click 'delete' button to display popup confirmation window
delete_btn = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('car-delete-modal-btn m-10-b')
delete_btn.click()

# click 'confirm' to delete object in popup window
submit = 'input[type="submit"]'
confirm_btn = self.selenium.find_element_by_id(submit)
confirm_btn.click()
```

I just can't seem to find proper selector for this button or it's a problem with a synchronization. Can someone help me fix it?

Sorry for my broken english and i hope you will understand what I'm trying to do here but I'm just starting with Django, tests, programming in general so not everything is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PixelEinstein 's Answer was in the right direction however I suppose the *WebDriverWait* will **timeout** as the node `input[@type="submit"]` is not the immediate child node of `[@id="confirmForm"]`.

Perhaps, you can induce *WebDriverWait* with the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='confirmForm']//input[@class='center-block btn btn-danger']"))).click()
#or
WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='confirmForm']//input[@class='center-block btn btn-danger']"))).submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines are causing your problem:

```
submit = 'input[type="submit"]'
confirm_btn = self.selenium.find_element_by_id(submit)
```

You are trying to pass **CSS** to an `id` selector.

I would try adding this before trying to click on the *submit*:

```
# Make sure to import these first
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/*[@id="confirmForm"]//input[@type="submit"]'))
```

Then try this click instead of `id`, **XPATH**:

```
self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="confirmForm"]//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```